# Geospatial Clustering using Presto

Tags: gis, postgis, presto

I have Lat/Lons as `POINT` coordinates and want to cluster them based on location with *presto*. For now, I am rounding the lat/lons to 2 decimals and converting them to strings, concatening them and finally grouping by. But this way I lose the information of individual points. Is there any good and clean way to do this (like may be `ST_Cluster*` functions in postgis) using presto?

Comment: Does `array_agg` over individual points help?

Answer (score 0):

Trino (formerly known as Presto SQL) seems to have https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/geospatial.html
geospatial functions, but nothing equivalent to st_cluster as you asked for.  Probably, you may use function like ST_Distance for concatenation instead of converting to decimal, strings..
Though not as clean as directly using st_cluster, but  a workaround to create clustering like behavior using existing geospatial functions